# Pass in @(Model.newsletterOptin ? true : false) value into checked key inside a dictionary for htmlhelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am trying to replace some html with html helpers and I am trying to pass a dictionary of HTMLAttributes into the CheckboxFor helper method.  My problem is that I do not know how to get this expression to work as an object param for my instantiation of the dictionary for the id checked.  The html looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox"
    id="newsletterOptin"
    name="newsletterOptin" 
    checked="@(Model.newsletterOptin ? true : false)" />
```

and the helper looks like this

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.newsletterOptin, new Dictionary<string, object>() {
    { "id", "newsletterOptin" },
    { "checked", "@(Model.newsletterOptin ? true : false)" }
})
```

How can I pass the `@(Model.newsletterOptin ? true : false)` so that it is used properly?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The `CheckBoxFor()` correctly sets the `checked` attribute based on the value of the property (if `newsletterOptin` is `true`, the checkbox will be checked, otherwise it will be unchecked).Your attempt just screws up model binding. And both `checked="true"` and `checked="false"` are identical - they both set the `checked` property - its the presence or absence of the attribute that determines it its checked

Comment: And setting `new { "id", "newsletterOptin" }` is pointless - the `CheckBoxFor()` (and all `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls) set the `id` attribute based on the property name. Your just overwriting it with exactly the same value if already is.

Answer (score 0):

Your helper starts with an `@` sign, which starts a code block in ASP.NET Razor. You don't need to use `@` again, because you can write it like any other plain C# code:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.newsletterOptin, new Dictionary<string, object> { 
    { "id", "newsletterOptin" },
    { "checked", Model.newsletterOptin ? "true" : "false" }
})
```